# Dynamic generated form in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I'm learning programming in yii2 framework, and I can't find out how to achieve specific task: I want to generate monthly statistic based on collected data. For this task, I need to generate form, that will wary on number of projects and users. For example:

```
Project 1: 500$
 user1 field (in fields I want to put percentage of above value)
 user2 field
 user3 field

project 2: 1000$
 user2 field
 user3 field
```

And so on. It's easy to do in structural way, and save results in serialized form, but this way I'm unable to validate (for example if sum of values in fields for given project excess 100% and if there was error, after sending form, data would be erased). 
Is it possible to achieve such task with Yii2?

edit:
currently I'm generating form this way:

controller:

```
        $date = "2015-05";
    $model = new Raport();
    $invoices = Faktura::find()->where(['LIKE','paid_date', $date])->all();

$projects = array();

        foreach($invoices as $invoice){
        $id = $invoice->project_id;
        $projects[$id]['faktury'][] = $invoice;
        $projects[$id]['model']= Project::find()->where(['id'=>$invoice->project_id])->one();
        $projects[$id]['value']+= $invoice->value_netto;
        $projects[$id]['users']= '' ;
        $checks = Check::find()->where(['project_id'=>$id])->all();
        if (empty($checks)){
            $projects[$id]['users']=$projects[$id]['model']->users;
        }else {
            foreach ($checks as $check) {
                $projects[$id]['users'][$check->user->id] = $check->user;
            }
        }
    }
```

view:

```
   foreach ($projects as $key => $project) {
    echo"<h2>".$project['model']->name."</h2>";
    echo 'project value: '.$project['value'];
    echo"<p>percentage value:</p>";

  //  echo"<pre>";
    foreach ($project['users'] as $user) {

        echo"<p>".$user->email."</p>";
        echo "<input name='Raport[".$key."][".$user->id."]'>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you are already creating the form in a dynamic way, create the model rules in the same dynamic way.

What you are trying to do is already done in the GII generator. Gii takes some fields (in GII's case database table fields) and it created the rules for the model and the fields on the form. In the end Gii writes those rules to the model file but you do not have to, you can just return that array as the result of the form. The same goes for the fields on the form, you can always have a

Basically you should create a Model that is not an Active Record model something like this https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/frontend/models/ContactForm.php. Instead of the way the rules function is created you should create that array based on "other things" (like your projects and users). You should create a function that does validation and that checks if the % is above 100 and tie it to the validation of some fields. A simple example would be

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [];
    foreach(['p1', 'p2'] as $project) {
        foreach(['u1', 'u2'] as $user) {
            $rules[] = [$project.'_'.$user, "required"];
        }
    }
    return $rules;
}
```

Afterwards, based on the same "other things" as a above you should create your form. Because the model and the view use the same fields it should all work out quite ok.

example view

```
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?php
        foreach(['p1', 'p2'] as $project) {
            foreach(['u1', 'u2'] as $user) {
                echo $form->field($model, $project.'_'.$user)->textInput() 
            }
        }
?>

...................
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: As I said, I'm learning it - so far I got no idea about how to design such model.

Comment: i put some examples, also take a look at Gii, understand what it does and how it does it.

Comment: okay, so I created fieldset model, creating it for each project and binding users properties like p1u1 - then on Post I'm executing $project['fs']->load(Yii::$app->request->post());  It returns true but doesn't bind entered values, do You have idea why it is so?

Comment: ah, I had a Typo in validation rules - looks like it works like a charm!

Comment: you got the idea anyway :)